# createCriteria and list syntax in Grails

Tags: grails, syntax, criteria

I'm checking the createCriteria method [here](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

This statement declares a HibernateCriteriaBuilder object

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
```

and then it calls

```
def results = c.list {
 like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
 and {
    between("balance", 500, 1000)
    eq("branch", "London")
 }
}
```

However, from the api, the HibernateCriteriaBuilder doesn't have any list() method. Do i miss something?

Also, can someone explain to me the more complicated **syntax** of the following:

```
def results = c.list (max: 10, offset: 10) {
   like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
}
```

Is it a list method that takes two arguments and a closure??

Answer (score 1):

This `list()` is dynamic method, generated/handled by HibernateCriteriaBuilder (see [source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/a9edf442f1710bfbf07e7a1079fcc1cd606f90dd/src/java/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java#L992))

And you're right, this syntax is for passing a closure, but current example also uses parameters as a map (`max: 10, offset: 10` is a map), so it's for a method like `list(Map params, Closure c)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about the list(), its a dynamic method, you just assume that it exists.

Below is a query with paging information - that says return maximum 10 records starting with offset 10 where holderFirstName is like Fred%

```
def results = c.list (max: 10, offset: 10) {
  like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
}
```